# Transfer files to external harddrive - USB to USB

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

I'd like to transfer files to this [Archos TV+ device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000S6R93W) from my Windows PC. (XP) Is it possible to connect the device over USB to USB like an external harddrive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need Cross-Over USB cable (~$25) to have asynchronous file transfer. 
http://www.nextag.com/crossover-usb-cable/products-html

Alternately, preferably use router, or as a last effort a switch. This may help file transfer much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the device you have you should do the following:

1. Connect both devices to your PC.
2. Transfer the files in question from your external hdd to the Archos device.

You will be unable to connect the external hdd to the Archos TV itself, it does not appear to be a USB Host device, which is required for it to be able to see the files on your external hdd.